# Generating an html table using javascript

Tags: javascript, html

My homework assignment is to generate a checkered html table (aka a chess board) using javascript. I have to use the getElementById and innerHTML properties to do it. I am supposed to generate html strings and add them to the document.

This is what I've written, when i open the page it is empty though, it isn't generating anything at all.

html/script:

```
<!doctype html>

<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="gameTableStyle.css">
<script>
function showTable() {
    var tableDiv = document.getElementById("tableDiv");
    tableDiv.innerHTML = genTable();
}

function genTable() {
    var html = "";
    var i = 0;
    var j = 0;
    var tClass = "white";
    html += "<table>";
    for (i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
        html += "<tr>";
        for (j = 0; j < 8; j++) {
            if (i % 2 = 0) {
                tClass = "black";
            }
            else {
                tClass = "white";
            }
            html += "<td>" + "</td>;
        }
        html += "</tr>";
    }
    html += "</table>"
    return html;
}

</script>
</head>

<body onload="showTable()">


<div id="tableDiv">

</div>

</body>

</html>
```

css:

```
.black {
color: black;
}

.white {
color: white;
}
```

This is my first class on html/javascript so I'm sure there are fancier ways to do this but we are specifically supposed to do it by generating the strings and inserting them in the document. I don't know what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: One obvious issue, which should appear if you check the error console. `html += "<td>" + "</td>;`  ... you are missing a closing quote.  I would go with `html += "<td> </td>";` Always check the console for errors first.

Comment: Use something like `var x = document.createElement("TABLE");` for creating new elements and parents it as a child on parent.

Comment: You must want `tClass` incorporated into your `td`s.

Comment: use `backticks` instead of `quotation`

Comment: Also an issue with `if (i % 2 = 0) ` , you want `if (i % 2 == 0) ` for a comparison. Check out: https://jsfiddle.net/gr0tjfq6/ . Not going a full answer as effectively you just have a couple of typos.

Comment: From the question: "we are specifically supposed to do it by generating the strings and inserting them in the document"

Comment: Thank you for the replies! Sorry the instructor hasnt even showed us how to check for errors or anything yet. These things i missed were helpful, thanks!

Comment: If you need to know how to check for errors (at least in Chrome), right click -> Inspect -> Console.